# Como pegar o valor da tabela a do input ao mesmo tempo - Angular

Tags: angular

Amigos, estou com um problema a ser resolvido. Tenho uma tabela dinamica que gera a quantidade de linhas junto de um input e tenho que salvar o id desse ngForm junto do input. Como consigo pegar esses dados somente na ação do botão salvar, sendo que agora ele está salvando a ultima informação do input.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="form">
                    <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let arr of conciliados; let i = index;">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" [busy]="isTableLoading">
                            <thead class="bg-light">
                                <tr>
                                   
                                    <th>{{ "Data/Hora Movimento" | localize }}</th>
                                    <th>{{ "Status" | localize }}</th>
                                    <th>{{ "Motivo" | localize }}</th>
                                    <th>{{ "Código Autorização/Barras" | localize }}</th>
                                    <th>{{ "Tipo Transação" | localize }}</th>
                                    <th>{{ "Rede" | localize }}</th>
                                    <th>{{ "Bandeira" | localize }}</th>
                                    <th>{{ "Valor Bruto" | localize }}</th>
                                    <th>{{ "Valor Liquido" | localize }}</th>
                                    <th>{{ "Taxa Cartão" | localize }}</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    
                                    <td>{{ conciliados[i].dataConciliacaoItem | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm' }}</td>
                                    <td *ngIf="conciliados[i].statusConciliacaoItem == 1">Conciliado</td>
                                    <td *ngIf="conciliados[i].statusConciliacaoItem == 2">Conciliado Parcialmente</td>
                                    <td>{{ conciliados[i].mensagem }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ conciliados[i].codigoAutorizacao}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ conciliados[i].transacaoId }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ conciliados[i].rede }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ conciliados[i].bandeira }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ conciliados[i].valorBruto | currency : 'BRL' }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ conciliados[i].valorLiquido | currency : 'BRL' }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ conciliados[i].taxaCalculada}}</td>
                                    
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <input type="text" formControlName="motivo" class="form-control" name="filtro.motivo" id="motivo" #motivo>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Preciso do i e do motivo de todas as linhas do conciliado.

Comment: Olá Grasielle. Tá um pouco difícil de entender o problema. Tu queres pegar o valor gerado dinamicamente da tabela e o valor digitado pelo usuário no input, certo? Não daria para ti pegar o valor da tabela da mesma forma que tu preencheste a tabela (já que ela é dinâmica, tu deves ter uma função que a preencha)...

Comment: Primeiro não entendi o modo que está utilizando o **ngFor**, vc percorre uma propriedade da classe que acredito que seja um **`array`** chamada `conciliados`, aí quando vai usar os valores do array vc faz **`<td>conciliados[i].algumaCoisa</td>`** pq? Se vc está percorrendo o array e guardando na variável **`arr`** no Html, teria que fazer assim: **`<td>arr.algumaCoisa</td>`**. Segundo como disse o Leonardo no comentário acima, não ficou claro o que deseja fazer, quais valores deseja pegar, como também não apresentou a função `salvar`.